# Column values are taking as 0 or nul in place of char data type in HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hadoop2

I have a table with one of the columns having char(3) datatype. The table creation statement is working fine. But, when a try to insert into that table with a char(3) data. The code is working fine.

But, when i select * the table i am seeing 0s and sometimes NUL in that respective columns in place of the value i am inserting.

Is there any possible reasons for that??

Answer (score 1):

Hive does not perform any type of datatype validation. So when you are inserting data with wrong schema inforamtion, it will be inserted without any issye, but same data cant be read, Null will come instead.

Please check schema information and prepare the input data as per the schema information.

Comment: Yes! But in my case while reading the data i am seeing 0 or sometimes NUL....it is something i am unable to connect.

Comment: can you share sample raw data and its schema information

Comment: It is something that i cannot share. The raw data is CSV file which is fed in a external table. Table load fine. Then with this table i populate a staging table with a coloumn having 'USD' as currency for all the rows with a insert command as normally we do. The external table is of deault storage and that of stagging table is of ORC type.

Comment: Thanks dreamcoder for your time....it's sorted. It was due to error in taking values. Wrong data was going in the right schema.